Standard order for monomials in infinitely many variables?
Is there any standardized way to order the terms in a polynomial when there are countably many variables?
I had the following in mind:
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty x_k^{n_k} \leq \prod_{k=1}^\infty x_k^{m_k}$$
if either
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kn_k < \sum_{k=1}^\infty km_k$$
or
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kn_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty km_k \quad\text{and}\quad (n_k) \leq (m_k)$$
where the final comparison is (edit: reverse?) lexicographic order of the sequence (the sums here are always well-defined since at most finitely many terms can be non-zero).
Thus the order begins as follows:
$$1 < x_1 < x_1^2 < x_2 < x_1^3 < x_1x_2 < x_3 < x_1^4 < x_1^2x_2 < x_2^2 < x_1x_3 < x_4 < ...$$
Does this have a name? Is there a better way to do this?
